# What are all the possible Accolades?

Tags: smite

In Smite, at the end game screen I've seen accolades for the number of single, double, triple, quadra, penta kills along with tower, phoenix and assisted kills. What are all the possible accolades?

Comment: I've also seen "Gold Fury Kill" and "Fire Giant Kill"

Comment: Isn't there a tower assist?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer I listed that in the question, "...along with tower, phoenix and assisted kills".

Comment: Hmm... I read that as assist for god kills, not tower kills since you can't kill an inanimate object.

Answer (score 2):

On the Xbox One, from the main menu you can go into Profile then select Accolades.  You will see the following list (correct as of version 3.9):

- Spree

  - Killing Spree (X3)
  - Rampage (X5)
  - Unstoppable (X7)
  - Divine (X9)
  - Immortal (X11)
  - Godlike (X13)
  - Shutdown
- Kills

  - First Blood
  - Assisted
  - Player Kill
  - Double Kill
  - Triple Kill
  - Quadra Kill
  - Penta Kill
- Matches

  - Completed Conquest
  - Completed Arena
  - Completed Assault
  - Completed Siege
  - Completed MOTD
  - Completed Joust Ranked
  - Completed Duel Ranked
  - Completed Conquest Ranked
  - Completed Clash Ranked
- Objective

  - Gold Fury Kill
  - Fire Giant Kill
  - Wild Juggernaut Kill
  - Siege Juggernaut Kill
  - Buff Camp Clear
  - Tower Kill
  - Phoenix Kill
  - Player Minion Kill
- Special

  - Shoot from the Hip
  - Hold the Line
  - Tower Dive
  - Objective Steal
  - Revenge

Note that you may also see Awards at the end of the game too (these will pop up mid-game too, or more accurately as soon as you earn them).  These are also found in the Profile menu (under Awards).  I won't list them because as of 3.9 there are 295.

Comment: This list appears to match what's on PC based on my experiences. I'd need to find a source in order to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

you've pretty much listed them all. Gold fury and Fire Giant accolades are game events only and not recorded/saved to your player history.

The only one missing is First blood (getting the first kill of the match)